# Why onnegotiationneeded is triggered only once?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, simple-peer

I am adding `tracks` to my peer and the first time `onnegotiationneeded` is triggered just fine. However, upon adding more `tracks` `onnegotiationneeded` is not triggered therefore the new `tracks` are not showing any effect. This is the main part of the code I am working with :

```
  const { id } = req.params
  peer[id] = new webrtc.RTCPeerConnection()
  const guest = { id, name: '', tracks: [], room }
  guest.tracks.forEach(t => peer[host.id].addTrack(t))

  const createNegotiation = async (peerID) => {
    peer[peerID].onnegotiationneeded = async () => {
      console.log('onnegotiationneededonnegotiationneeded')
      const offer = await peer[peerID].createOffer()
      await peer[peerID].setLocalDescription(offer)
      dc.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'onnegotiationneeded', "sdp": peer[peerID].localDescription }))
    }
  }
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It turns out that `onnegotiationneeded` only fires once at `removeTrack` or `addTrack` and is not able to detect further additional tracks. Therefore I ended up reestablishing the connection allover again through a

```
  const reNew = async (peerID) => {
      console.log('RENEW WITH PEER ID '  , peerID)
      const offer = await peer[peerID].createOffer()
      await peer[peerID].setLocalDescription(offer)
      peer[peerID].dcm.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'RENEW', "sdp": peer[peerID].localDescription }))
  }
```